# How to make a condition, where the bot will only respond to a specific channel in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So i found a src online which is a chatgpt model in discord. And it keeps sending responses in all the channels, I was wondering if there is a way to make it only able to respond in a specific channel via channel id or so

import discord
import openai
import os

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
openai.api_key = os.getenv("KEY")
class Chatbot(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Logged on as {0}!".format(self.user))
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        input_content = message.content

        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages = [{"role": "user", "content": input_content}]
        )
        assistant_response = response["choices"][0]['message']["content"]
        await message.channel.send(assistant_response)
bot = Chatbot(intents=intents)
bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use message command (with prefix, not slash), and you need to ask a question to the bot first. Then, you could use `on_message` event to check about this.

```py
async def on_message(message):
  if message.channel.id != YOUR_SPECIFIC_CHANNEL_ID:
    return
  
  # respond
  await message.channel.send("response")
```